# I need a free php bug tracker

Tags: php, bug-tracking

I need a free bug tracker for my small project. I need keep track of bug, todo list and test case. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out mantis http://www.mantisbt.org/

If it's a small project, though, you might want to think about using something with less overhead than a PHP-based system.  Are you the only person working on it?  A whiteboard and post-it notes might be less upkeep and could ultimately save you time and energy that would be better spent on the project itself.

Comment: Thanks for your link. We got three guys work over the internet so we need a web based system.

Answer (score 2):

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) is coded in Ruby, but if you can install it, I would highly recommend it.

Comment: +1 Redmine is IMO one of the best and most flexible tools on the Open Source market fpr such tasks.

Comment: They don't do a very good job in the presentation department. I was confused visiting the site, not sure if it is exactly what I am after which is a bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

If you are the only user checkout Task Coach: http://www.taskcoach.org/

It is very easy to use, and works great. Runs on all OS's

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it contains a seeding server included is tested:
http://www.binpress.com/app/phptracker/177

Answer (score 0):

How about CandyCane which is port of Redmine into CakePHP.
I wish it can meet your expectation.

https://github.com/yandod/candycane

Comment: It's buggy. Not recommending.

Answer (score 0):

Try flyspray: http://www.flyspray.org/
Simple, specific, fast.